# is there a broadcast if network provider changes in Android?

Tags: android

Is that possible that my android app receive a broadcast while my network provider changed?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.It is posible to find this.

see the code

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String TAG = "NetworkReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     boolean isNetworkDown = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);  // 2
    if (isNetworkDown) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: NOT connected, stopping UpdaterService");
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: connected, starting UpdaterService");
    }
}
```

In the Manifes file add this code

```
<receiver android:name="NetworkStateReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: the receiver seems not work, when i change the network provider manually, the receiver isn't triggered. which i want is to do sth when the network provider switched from another. would you give me more advices? thx very much.

Comment: @Matt declare the permission in manifest file "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>"

Comment: it seems not work, the android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE cannot send a broadcast while switching a network provider to another, oops~